# Is torsion $0$ for an osculating curve in Euclidean space?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves

A curve is called osculating curve if its position vector lies on its osculating plane. Osculating plane for the curve $\alpha(s)$ at some point on it is generated by the tangent vector and normal vector of $\alpha$ at that point. i.e.,
$\alpha(s)=\lambda_1(s)t(s)+\lambda_2(s)n(s)$, for some function for some function $\lambda_1(s)$ and $\lambda_2(s)$.
 Is torsion $0$ for an osculating curve in Euclidean space?

Comment: Please say exactly what “its position vector lies on its osculating plane” means.

Comment: I am explain by editing the question, please give a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**:  Differentiate, use the Frenet equations, and then use linear independence of $T,N,B$.